# Odd chord progression sounds perfect to my ears

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I was playing yesterday and made up this 4 bar chord progression:

Cm, F, C, Fm

It's odd I guess, but it sounds perfect to what I am singing over it.

Does it comply with music rules and is it anyway close to a normal chord progression used in classical music for instance? How can I understand this chord progression from the point of view of music theory?

Comment: Music rules? What are they..?

Comment: Music rules are those prescription rules given by teachers of music who give you classical music theory.

Comment: It's doubtful that your sequence would have appeared in any classical music.

Comment: Why not? Is it unique?

Answer (score 3):

Your progression complies with common practice period music rules if we apply enough tonicizations.

Cm to F is i to IV in C minor. Borrowing the IV chord from C major is allowed.

F to C is IV to I in C major (or I to V in F major).

C to Fm is I to iv in C major. Borrowing the iv chord from C minor is allowed (and it's a tactic I've used a fair few times before). Alternately, this is also V to i in F minor.

If your chord progression loops, Fm to Cm is iv to i in C minor.

Comment: Don't even have to borrow from C major. The appropriate notes are already there, in C melodic minor.

Comment: Not certain whether the word 'allowed' should be allowed to be used in music!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing about your chord progression that is "against the rules." You can analyze it in a number of different ways. A lot of how you would analyze it depends on the rest of your piece.

Don't get too caught up in doing it "right." Beethoven was heavily criticized by many of his contemporaries for breaking rules of theory; much was made about the "dissonance" of the opening chords of his first symphony. One of Chopin's contemporaries said this: "In search of ear-rending dissonances, torturous transitions, sharp modulations, repugnant contortions of melody and rhythm, Chopin is altogether indefatigable." And that doesn't begin to equal what some critics had to say about Debussy and Stravinsky in their times.

So, if you like it (I like it, too) then by all means use it. Passing the "smell test" is more important than whether it's a "normal" chord progression. Much of the world's great music was written while breaking the rules of its time.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, trying to arrange other instruments to fit in nicely with this verse progression.

Comment: Music would have vegetated had it not been for people breaking out of the 'rules'. Often it was at the cost of their recognition in their own lifetimes. Luckily for those who later realised, we have growth and development. Not always acceptable to everyone, but we need those pioneers!

Comment: @SovereignSun That is a problem no matter what chords you are using! I'm sure you'll solve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks uncommon indeed, and I doesn't look classical to me.

According to my interpretation, this progression is in Fm, because the C Fm (V i) at the end is a very strong resolution. So, the only chord out of the scale would be the F, borrowed from F major.

Though, when the progression starts, Cm F sound like a ii V of Bb. When C comes after F, it sounds like a V and the progression is biased towards F, but Fm comes instead, which is unexpected, but also makes sense and provides resolution.

For me, the Roman Numeral analysis would be: v I V i.

The best features, in my opinion, are the presence of C, when one would expect a Bb, and then an Fm when one would now expect and F.

Comment: Well, I kind of like the way it sounds.

Comment: And it's fine.  Don't torture yourself by trying to decide what key it's in though!

Comment: @LaurencePayne - aw, I think we really need to know...

Comment: What's all this 'borrowing' about? Totally unnecessary.

Comment: Well, it's just a definition. Worth mentioning, right?

Comment: Of course it's just a definition,. but pointless in this instance, because there's no need to 'borrow' from anywhere. -1.

Comment: @Tim But the fact that there is no need to borrow from anywhere conflicts with the definition of borrowing. There is always no need to 'borrow', so borrowing would never be applicable.

Comment: You miss the point. If one borrows from somewhere, that's what needs to happen. However, here, the notes are available anyway. So there is no need for any borrowing. There is not always no need to borrow. in other words, sometimes there is a need to borrow. Here there is not.

Comment: @Tim I think I must be missing the point too. In what key are all four of these chords available, without borrowing the parallel chord? Classical theory defines a "borrowed chord" as the parallel major or minor of a diatonic chord.

Comment: @BobRodes - the above answer suggests that the F chord is 'borrowed' from F major. Assuming we use the notes from C minor, the notes to make F maj. are in there. Then we have the 'problem' of C maj. If anything, *that's* the 'borrowed' chord. We have the dilemma of what key it may be in. To me it doesn't sound like any chord will necessarily be the home/final sounding one. What key? I don't know which I'd plump for. I challenged the borrowing stated in this answer, as in Cm, FAC all exist, as they do in Cmaj.

Comment: @Tim I see now. It's reasonable to say that the notes to make F major are available in the C minor key, by including the notes of the melodic minor scale in the "available" ones. It also seems reasonable to say that chords that aren't in the natural minor scale, but are in the parallel major scale, are borrowed chords. That is the formal definition of a borrowed chord, after all. The fact that the dominant 7th in a minor key is nearly always the one used in its parallel major key doesn't mean perforce that it isn't "borrowed" from that key and, rather, is "part of" the notes in the minor key.

Comment: @Tim As for which key it's in, I have no idea either. We'd need more context to determine that.

Comment: @Tim Oh, I got it now. As I stated, for me it sounds like the tonal center is F, and the tonality is Fm. Then, in this case, the F is borrowed from F major. If I had said it was in C minor, then you would be right.